# AWK: Insert copy of column in the middle of csv

Tags: awk

Example csv:

```
AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

Now i wan't a copy column 2 (BBB) and add it in front of column 3 so the file looks like:

```
AAA, BBB, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ cat test.txt
AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH

$ awk -F, '{$2=$2","$2}1' OFS=, test.txt
AAA, BBB, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
AAA, BBB, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
AAA, BBB, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

Comment: *much* cleaner than my answer :)

Comment: In this case I think this is enough: awk '{$2=$2" "$2}1' test.txt

Answer (score 4):

`awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' file.csv`

#### Example:

```
 ➤ echo "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH" | awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}'
 AAA, BBB, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a solution i already thought about but the real csv file has more then 50 fields so the print gets very long.

Comment: check out @Kamaraj's answer, should do the trick for you